# External keyboard backlight problem

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, backlight

I tried to turn on my external keyboard's backlight using the commands (`xset led on`, `xset -led 3` then `xset led 3`) on Ubuntu 22.04, and these commands are not working.

Answer (score 0):

If a value between 1 and 32 is given, that LED will be turned on or off depending on the existence of a preceding dash. `xset led 3` would turn led #3 on. `xset -led 3` would turn it off. The particular LED values may refer to different LEDs on different hardware.

Example using `led 3`:

```
xset -led 3 # turn backlight off
xset led 3 # turn backlight on
```

This would work if the device number of your keyboard's backlight is 3, otherwise try a different number between 1 and 32.